# java get current file content

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I created a new extension with jnlp - I used the association tag.
after clicking a file with the special extension, It's open the program.
How the program can get the content of the file?

Comment: @gd1 *"I didn't understand anything."*  That is generally a good time to not say (or comment) anything either.

Comment: @gd1 better to let people think you're a fool then open your mouth and remove all doubt...maybe I should take my own advice sometimes :P

Comment: You are right guys, 100% my fault, but the comment wasn't meant to be offensive. More, I would have enjoyed answering the question... if just I could understand it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [file services demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) has a complete example of declaring the `.zzz` extension.

Basically the file name is passed as a `String` in the arguments to the `main(String[])` method.  The arguments is preceded by a string with either open or print.

Once the code has the file name, create a `File` and load it as you might load any other file.

Answer (score 2):

The file in question would be past in as an argument to the main program.

From there, you would read the file as normal